# Cant run sox from php exec()

Tags: php, html, sox

when i run this code in my php

```
$location = "/var/www/html/recordings/$date/$file";
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/sox $location test.wav');
```

i get this return

```
/usr/bin/sox: SoX v14.4.1 Usage summary: [gopts] [[fopts] infile]... [fopts] outfile [effect [effopt]]... SPECIAL FILENAMES (infile, outfile): - Pipe/redirect input/output (stdin/stdout); may need -t -d, --default-device Use the default audio device (where available) -n, --null Use the `null' file handler; e.g. with synth effect -p, --sox-pipe Alias for `-t sox -' SPECIAL FILENAMES (infile only): "|program [options] ..." Pipe input from external program (where supported) http://server/file Use the given URL as input file (where supported) GLOBAL OPTIONS (gopts) (can be specified at any point before the first effect): --buffer BYTES Set the size of all processing buffers (default 8192) --clobber Don't prompt to overwrite output file (default) --combine concatenate Concatenate all input files (default for sox, rec) --combine sequence Sequence all input files (default for play) -D, --no-dither Don't dither automatically --effects-file FILENAME File containing effects and options -G, --guard Use temporary files to guard against clipping -h, --help Display version number and usage information --help-effect NAME Show usage of effect NAME, or NAME=all for all --help-format NAME Show info on format NAME, or NAME=all for all --i, --info Behave as soxi(1) --input-buffer BYTES Override the input buffer size (default: as --buffer) --no-clobber Prompt to overwrite output file -m, --combine mix Mix multiple input files (instead of concatenating) --combine mix-power Mix to equal power (instead of concatenating) -M, --combine merge Merge multiple input files (instead of concatenating) --magic Use `magic' file-type detection --multi-threaded Enable parallel effects channels processing --norm Guard (see --guard) & normalise --play-rate-arg ARG Default `rate' argument for auto-resample with `play' --plot gnuplot|octave Generate script to plot response of filter effect -q, --no-show-progress Run in quiet mode; opposite of -S --replay-gain track|album|off Default: off (sox, rec), track (play) -R Use default random numbers (same on each run of SoX) -S, --show-progress Display progress while processing audio data --single-threaded Disable parallel effects channels processing --temp DIRECTORY Specify the directory to use for temporary files -T, --combine multiply Multiply samples of corresponding channels from all input files (instead of concatenating) --version Display version number of SoX and exit -V[LEVEL] Increment or set verbosity level (default 2); levels: 1: failure messages 2: warnings 3: details of processing 4-6: increasing levels of debug messages FORMAT OPTIONS (fopts): Input file format options need only be supplied for files that are headerless. Output files will have the same format as the input file where possible and not overriden by any of various means including providing output format options. -v|--volume FACTOR Input file volume adjustment factor (real number) --ignore-length Ignore input file length given in header; read to EOF -t|--type FILETYPE File type of audio -e|--encoding ENCODING Set encoding (ENCODING may be one of signed-integer, unsigned-integer, floating-point, mu-law, a-law, ima-adpcm, ms-adpcm, gsm-full-rate) -b|--bits BITS Encoded sample size in bits -N|--reverse-nibbles Encoded nibble-order -X|--reverse-bits Encoded bit-order --endian little|big|swap Encoded byte-order; swap means opposite to default -L/-B/-x Short options for the above -c|--channels CHANNELS Number of channels of audio data; e.g. 2 = stereo -r|--rate RATE Sample rate of audio -C|--compression FACTOR Compression factor for output format --add-comment TEXT Append output file comment --comment TEXT Specify comment text for the output file --comment-file FILENAME File containing comment text for the output file --no-glob Don't `glob' wildcard match the following filename AUDIO FILE FORMATS: 8svx aif aifc aiff aiffc al amb amr-nb amr-wb anb au avr awb caf cdda cdr cvs cvsd cvu dat dvms f32 f4 f64 f8 fap flac fssd gsm gsrt hcom htk ima ircam la lpc lpc10 lu mat mat4 mat5 maud nist ogg paf prc pvf raw s1 s16 s2 s24 s3 s32 s4 s8 sb sd2 sds sf sl sln smp snd sndfile sndr sndt sou sox sph sw txw u1 u16 u2 u24 u3 u32 u4 u8 ub ul uw vms voc vorbis vox w64 wav wavpcm wv wve xa xi PLAYLIST FORMATS: m3u pls AUDIO DEVICE DRIVERS: alsa EFFECTS: allpass band bandpass bandreject bass bend biquad chorus channels compand contrast dcshift deemph delay dither divide+ downsample earwax echo echos equalizer fade fir firfit+ flanger gain highpass hilbert input# ladspa loudness lowpass mcompand mixer* noiseprof noisered norm oops output# overdrive pad phaser pitch rate remix repeat reverb reverse riaa silence sinc spectrogram speed splice stat stats stretch swap synth tempo treble tremolo trim upsample vad vol * Deprecated effect + Experimental effect # LibSoX-only effect EFFECT OPTIONS (effopts): effect dependent; see --help-effect
```

any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, variables can be expanded in string literals if you use [double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). Change it to:

```
$location = "/var/www/html/recordings/$date/$file";
echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/sox $location test.wav");
```

Comment: i did that and it stopped printing out the long message but still does convert the file

Comment: Can't help you there. Check your docs. This was a PHP question/

Comment: i don't think thats right because the parentheses are different colors